# Angular 4 detecting changes on app.component

Tags: angular

I have navbar in my `app.component.ts`, with `ngIf`, so after login I am supposed to see the log out button, but that not happening, because `app.component` doesn't detect changes

app.component.html:

```
<div>
  <nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
    <div class='container-fluid'>
      <a class='navbar-brand'>{{title}}</a>
      <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/welcome']">Home</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/apartments']">Apartments List</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div *ngIf="currentUser">
      <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><button (click)="logout()" class="btn btn-default">Log-out</button></p>
      <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Signed in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">{{currentUser}}</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from "./shared/auth.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[AuthService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Product List App';
  currentUser: string;
  constructor(private _authService: AuthService) {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  }
  logout() {
    this._authService.logout();
    this.currentUser = undefined;
  }
}
```

When I perform login, i do:         `localStorage.setItem('currentUser',JSON.stringify(user));`

but my `app.component` is not detecting that the currentUser has been changed, and therefore I cant see the logged in user name and the log out button.
(I need to do refresh to page in-order to see them)
How I can solve this without putting the login functionality in my `app.component.ts` ?

Comment: what about doing 
`this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));`
in an ngOnInit or ngViewLoaded? instead the constructor?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/YRz25z7uULhlXdfTlS30?p=preview I think the issue is with your login, because setting currentUser in the constructor works.

Comment: How I trigger currentUser(in app.component) and change it from login component when logging in

Comment: You could use a service with an observable, and in your constructor subscribe to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on my phone so syntax may be slightly off.

If you created a login service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    public uname = new Subject<any>():
    public uname$ = this.uname.asObservable();

    public publishUsername(data: any) {
        this.uname.next(data);
}
```

Then in your constructor:

```
constructor(private lin: LoginService) {
    this.lin.uname$.subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.currentUser = data;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you login all you are doing is setting a value in local storage. This isn't going to trigger any changes. When you refresh the browser it is fetching this new value in your constructor and rendering it.

You need to set the currentUser property when you login.